# How to create a rolling window function to detect spikes in a time-series dataset in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, time-series, moving-average, standard-deviation

I am working with a large time-series dataset that includes readings from sensors measuring various metrics such as temperature, power, pressure, etc. in a thermal generation plant.  The data is collected in varying base frequencies of 5-25 seconds, and has been collected since the start of 2019.  Some of the sensor datasets carry over 12 million points.

My goal is to detect errors in the dataset, caused by the sensor giving a faulty reading.  An important thing to note with this project, I am not looking for high values of the equipment (i.e. temperature rising at a concerning rate).  I am looking for incorrect readings in the dataset that appear as single points way outside the distribution that appear to occur randomly.

I have tried some machine learning techniques such as One-class SVM, UMAP, some Pyod techniques but it is difficult to train and evaluate the model when the dataset doesn't have labels indicating whether a point is erroneous or not.  With most of these techniques, it detects those anomalies where the temperature is rising and the sensor is working correctly, which is not what we want.

Another issue with this dataset is that the plant goes through many different states throughout the time-series dataset.  Sometimes the plant will be shut down, and all the values will be 0, which is expected.  Any modelling technique will pick up those 0 points as errors which is not what we want.

I have decided to create a function using a rolling window of size n.  For that window, calculate the mean, median, and standard deviation.  If the next point entering is let's say 2 std deviations away from the window mean, then consider that an error.  Using this rolling window will eliminate the effect of the different operating states of the plant and hopefully avoid detecting those **expected** anomalies.

Does anyone have any suggestions to create this rolling window detection function? Or maybe some other possible techniques?  This is a univariate problem and we will be running it on each of the sensors individually.

Answer (score 0):

If your time series sensor data is in a pandas data frame, there are built in rolling window calculations such as mean and std that you could use as you mentioned in finding outliers.

I think something like:

```
import pandas as pd

window = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : [5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5]})
std = df.rolling(window).std()
mean = df.rolling(window).mean()
```

You could use the z-score as the way of classifying an "outlier".
That is the data point minus the mean, all divided by the std.

```
z = (x - mean) / std
```

The further from 0 the more of an outlier it is.